# Characteristics of Good & Bad Times

Tags: vedas, scripture, bhagavad-gita, upanishads

Time is a powerful thing and it appears to be the nature of time to change.

So my questions are:

- Are there slokas that talk about the characteristics of good time and bad time in human life?
- How is one expected to act when the time is in his/her favor and also when it is not?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of the sanskrit **Subhashitam** (सुभाषितं)  about good or bad time of human life and how one should act in those times.

> **उदये सविता रक्तो रक्तश्चस्तस्तमये तथा । सम्पतौ च विपत्तौ च**
>   **महतामेकरूपता।।**
>
> udayé savitā rakto raktashchāstamayé tathā | sampattau cha vipattau
>   cha mahatāmékarūpatā ||
>
> **Meaning** - Like the Sun is red in sunrise and sunset, similarly the
>   Great Ones remain same (not disturbed) in good and bad
>   times.[Source](http://blog.practicalsanskrit.com/2015/01/be-equanimous-in-good-and-bad-times.html)
>
> **श्रमेण दुःखं यत्किंश्चिकार्यकालेनुभुयते । कालेन स्मर्यमाणं तत प्रमोद।।**
>
> Shramena dukham yakinschitkaryakalenubhuyate Kaalena smayaramanam tat
>   pramoda.
>
> **Meaning** - While working hard we do feel a bit of sadness ,due to
>   adverse condiation.But surely in future when we think of "that" work
>   it gives us happiness and satisfaction.[Source](https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/dokka/sanskrit-subhashitas-with-english-meaning.)
>
> **गते शोको न कर्तव्यो भविष्यं नैव चिंतयेत्। वर्तमानेन कालेन वर्तयंति**
>   **विचक्षणाः॥**
>
> Gate shoko na kartavya bhavishyam naiva chitntayet Vartamanen kalena
>   vartayanti vichakshana
>
> **Meaning** - One should not regret the past. One should not worry about
>   the future.Wise men act by the present time.[Source](http://sanskrit-quote.blogspot.in)
>
> **न कश्चिदपि जानाति  अतः श्वः करणीयानि किं कस्य श्वो भविष्यति**
>   **।कुर्यादद्धैव वुद्धिमान् ॥**
>
> Na kashcidapi janati ath shwa karaniyani kim kasya shwo bhavishyati|
>   Kuryadwaiva vudbhiman
>
> **Meaning** -  No one knows what will happen tomorrow. So, wise people do today what
>   should be done tommorow.
>
> **स्व्भावं न जहात्येव साधुरापद्गतोऽपि सन् । कर्पूरः पाव्कस्पृष्टः सौरभं**
>   **लभतेतराम् ॥**
>
> Swabhavam na jhatyeva sadhurapadnopi san l Karpurah paakwasprustah
>   saurrbhm labhteram ll
>
> **Meaning** - A good person never gives up his nature even when he is
>   caught in calamity. Camphor caught with fire emits more
>   frgrance.[Source](http://sanskrit.samskrutam.com/en.literature-shloka-subhaasitam.ashx)
>
> **अस्थिरं जीवितं  लोके अस्थिरो धन यौवने . अस्थिराः पुत्रदाराश्च**
>   **धर्मकीर्तिर्द्वयं  स्थिरं .**
>
> Asthiram jeewitam loke asthiro dhana youwane. asthiraah putradaraashch
>   dharmakeertirdwayam sthiram.
>
> **Meaning**-    In this world the period for which a person will be alive
>   is uncertain and so also how long his wealth, youth, children and wife
>   will remain with him is uncertain.  Only the righteous behaviour and
>   the resultant  reputation (fame) of a person remains permanent (even
>   after his death).
>
> **सर्वाभीष्ट प्रदो नित्यं सन्मार्गेणैव गच्छताम्**
>   **विचित्रमेतद्विद्वान्स्तु  जङ्गमः  कल्पपादपः**
>
> Sarvaabhishta prado nityam sanmaargenaiva gacchataam
>   Vichitrametadvidwaanstu jangasmah kalpapaadapah.
>
> **Meaning** -  One should always follow the path of righteousness which is
>   unique and wonderful and fulfils all wishes of learned persons, who
>   are like a "Kalpataru" in a forest of ordinary trees.[Source](http://mcjoshi21.blogspot.in/2012_11_01_archive.html)

Comment: Thank you. This is interesting & to the point. Do you mind if we wait for some more time if anyone has other inputs?

Comment: Related meta [Are Sanskrit Subhashitas valid references?](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/626/are-sanskrit-subhashitas-valid-references)

Comment: @sv. Sorry taht was my fault, they were getting flags , so I deleted them, forgot to delete the reply, I think meta reply is enough in comment. As I do respect you intention but comment under this question was not getting reciprocated well and it's better to be discussed on meta first, featured the meta post for now.